# Tabs on windows with custom buffers

Tags: buffers, window, tabs

I am new to Emacs and I am trying to set up a decent workflow for projects I already have.

What I want to do is to be able to have tabs of buffers on each window (not frame). What I want essentially is, having a tiled configuration of windows, to commit each window on a specific set of buffers, e.g. perhaps I want the upper left window to only cycle between 3 specific buffers. If that does not involve tabs but rather a non-visible set of buffers, I don't mind, but I want to be able to manually set the tabs/buffers assigned to each window - no automatic grouping based on filtering, for start at least.

After a bit of searching, the solutions I found ([TabBar](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/TabBarMode), [awesome-tab](https://github.com/manateelazycat/awesome-tab)) were either tabs that had some type of filtering grouping for all the available buffers, or tabs that involved switching the whole screen of windows to another. So here I am.

Any proposed solutions?

Comment: Can you give names of the solutions you've looked at?

Comment: @DoMiNeLa10 Tabbar, awesome-tab. At least I did not find a solution readily available for what I want, and I am not good enough at Emacs to thoroughly investigate the matter. If the solution is in one of these and I just have not seen it, let me know.

Comment: Can you add these to your post? It is expected to show some effort was put into the problem before posting a question on Stack Exchange.

Comment: If it is possible to store an arbitrary value (e.g., a list) in the window-parameters, then I may have an idea similar to how frame-bufs (by Alp Aker) stores a custom list in the frame-parameters.  I have not played around with that idea, but that is where I would start.  You need to be able to store window-local data to best accomplish your goal; however, there may be other solutions using buffer-local values that store window-local values -- that is not ideal in my opinion, but may be an avenue to explore also.

Comment: @lawlist I started using Emacs days ago, and I am searching for ready solutions to simple needs in order to get to a workflow comfortable for me, and then pick up skills as I go. I have written enough LISP to know my way around, but it is still too early for me to start messing with custom solutions in Emacs as I still got things to grasp regarding its structure and perks. If no ready solution is found in time, perhaps I will revisit my question to post my own solutions, I hope soon.